# Changing request inside Retrofit CallAdapter

Tags: retrofit2

I have an API that returns paginated responses. I've built a CallAdapter that can be used as

```
@GET("books")
PaginatedCall<Book> getBooks();
```

and then use it as

```
List<Book> firstPageOfBooks = getBooks().execute();
```

or

```
getBooks().enqueue(new Callback() {
    void onResponse(List<Book> books) {
        ...
    }
});
```

and returns a list of books on page 1. But I'd like to be able to fetch the second page of results, and I'd also like to be able to fetch *all* pages of the results, using just the CallAdapter. So I'd like to be able to call

```
List<Book> secondPage = getBooks().getPage(2);
```

or even

```
List<Book> allBooks = getBooks().allPages();

getBooks().enqueueAllPages(new Callback() {
    void onResponse(List<Book> allBooks) {
        ...
    }
});
```

etc

(I'm aware I could write

```
@GET("books")
PaginatedCall<Book> getBooks(@Query("page") int page);
```

but I have many such endpoints and consider it clutter, and I can't write an `allPages` method using this technique.)

To do this properly, I want to be able to take the `Call` object in my CallAdapter's execute() method, and add parameters to the request. I have an ugly way of doing this right now where I can get `call.request().newBuilder()`, add parameters to the URL, then use an OkHttpClient to make that request - this gets me the API I want, but it feels wrong to be bypassing retrofit in this way. It also means that, because I no longer have access to `call.enqueue`, I have to manage my own ThreadPool, call cancellation needs a lot of manual work, etc.

Ideally I want to do:

```
Call<..> newCall = myCall.builder().request(newRequest).build();
newCall.enqueue( ... );
```

Is there any way of creating a new Call in code, rather than retrofit just handing me something?

I can change the request with a NetworkInterceptor, so that *might* work, but there's no way of sending information from the CallAdapter to the NetworkInterceptor (and it feels weird).